# Find which coordinates to use based upon vector input in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, coordinates

I am given 5 different point coordinates 
`A=[0 0];`
`B=[1 1];`
`C=[2 1];`
`D=[1 2];`
`E=[2 2];`

Then I will be given an input. This input will describe which of these points I need to use for this particular iteration. (Essentially the user will input which points are needed). For example an input vector can be V=[1 0 1 0 0]; meaning I need to look at points A and C only. Then based off of this input, I then need to use a TSP type algorithm to solve for the shortest path between these coordinates. With this example, I would input matrix Coordinate=[0 0; 2 1]; into my algorithm to find the shortest path.

I am not sure how to automatically generate the matrix 'Coordinate' above based upon a user input of which points to look at.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Store it as a double matrix:

```
A = [0 0
     1 1
     2 1
     1 2
     2 2];
```

Then access the rows you need with `V = [1 0 1 0 0];`

```
A(logical(V),:)
```